# Stage file in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I would like to know if it is possible to stage a file using the git GUI of Android Studio. I saw the option to commit some files that were modified but not an option to just stage a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I assume you're using Git, isn't it just VCS -> Git -> Add?

Comment: Is there a way to add more than one file at a time?  i.e. the Android Studio equivalent of `git add .`

Answer (score 0):

- if you want add just one file  click on VSC tab :  VCS -> Git -> Add
- if u want add all files at once , right click on which folder you want then click on Git option :
  Git -> Add

it's equivalent of git ( add . ) command